# TensorFlow input pipeline for deployment on CloudML

Tags: pandas, input, tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I'm relatively new to TensorFlow and I'm having trouble modifying some of the examples to use batch/stream processing with input functions. More specifically, what is the 'best' way to modify this script to make it suitable for training and serving deployment on Google Cloud ML?

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/learn/text_classification.py

Something akin to this example:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/census/estimator/trainer

I can package it up and train it in the cloud, but I can't figure out how to apply even the simple vocab_processor transformations to an input tensor. I know how to do it with pandas, but there I can't apply the transformation to batches (using the chunk_size parameter). I would be very happy if I could reuse my pandas preprocessing pipelines in TensorFlow.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have 3 options

1) You cannot reuse pandas preprocessing pipelines in TF. However, you could start TF with the output of your pandas preprocessing. So you could build a vocab and convert the text words to integers, and save a new preprocessed dataset to disk. Then read the integer data (which is encoding your text) in TF to do training.

2) You could build a vocab outside of TF in pandas. Then inside TF, after reading the words, you can make a table to map the text to integers. But if you are going to build a vocab outside of TF, you might as well do the transformation at the same time outside of TF, which is option 1.

3) Use tensorflow_transform. You can call tft.string_to_int() on the text column to automatically build the vocab and convert to integers. The output of tensorflow_transform is preprocessed data in tf.example format. Then training can start from the tf.example files. This is again option 1 but with tf.example files. If you want to run prediction on raw text data, this option allows you to make an exported graph that has the same text preprocessing built in, so you don't have to manage the preprocessing step at prediction time. However, this option is the most complicated as it introduces two additional ideas: tf.example files and beam pipelines.

For examples of tensorflow_transform see https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/criteo_tft

and

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/reddit_tft

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I don't have a problem with training. Right now I just read in the data in pandas and apply the vocab_processor transformation and convert it to an input tensor (so option 1 and 2). But that doesn't help at serving time, where I get raw text. I was trying to make the preprocessing step part of the serving_input_fn, but I don't really know how to 'register' the serving_input_fn if that makes sense.
I will give option 3) a try.